# Exporting *.png sequence from *.fla with C++

Tags: c++, resources, adobe, png, fla

I need an animation in my program. My designer draws animation in Flash and provides me with *.fla file. All I need is to grab 30-40 PNGs from this file and store them within my internal storage.

Is it possible grab resources from *.fla with C++ ? Probably, some Adobe OLE objects can help?

Please, advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have abode CS? You can just open the file in that and grab the images from there, and then import it into your C++ project. Why would you need to grab the resource with C++?

Comment: i know that in some video-game a lots of stuffs like menu and guis are done in flash: some way to import swfs into c++ should exist.. but i don't know how..

Comment: @FrozenWasteland, I do have adobe CS, but I need to make it in code. The program must have an ability to load *.fla on-fly.

Comment: @nkint, I think you are talking about ActiveX control for Flash. I need images from *.fla to overlay them on my video. Just playing *.fla is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

1. You are using CS5
2. The assets used internally in the FLA are already PNG's as you want them to be.

Then simply get the FLA saved as a [XFL](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=1986) file, and you will be able to grab them from the library folder ( but then why not just get them to mail you the pngs ? )

So if for some reason you can only get access to the fla and not the designer, then you can do it programatically by renaming the fla to .zip, extracting.. and you have the XFL format.

Answer (score 4):

If I asked an artist to make me an icon I wouldn't expect to need to write code to convert a .3DS model into a usable icon format.

You can save yourself a lot of time and hassle by having your designer use **File->Export** and give you PNGs of the layers and frames instead of a .FLA file if that's the format you require for your implementation.

If that's not possible for some reason then you can probably find a flash decompiler that has a command line option which you could launch from your program to extract assets as part of your loading sequence but that is generally frowned upon because this is not the intended use of the proprietary format for .swf/.fla anymore than you should design applications to extract source code from a binary executable.